# JSON Parsing of ADSB Data

Tags: python, json, parsing

Coding this using Wing IDE. When running my code, it opens up decoder.py and provides the following error: **File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 367, in decode
  raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 341 - line 29 column 1 (char 340 - 15199)**

I've looked around google and SO, but haven't been able to match a root cause to my specific example. Any ideas?

The end goal is to parse ADS-B data from adsbexchange.
For the record, I also replaced the final print line with something more simple like `print parsed_json` but the results were the same.

```
import json

json_string = """{"Id":3429058,"Rcvr":11182,"HasSig":true,"Sig":6,"Icao":"3452C2","Bad":false,"FSeen":"\/Date(1512567030924)\/","CMsgs":2,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":0,"Species":0,"EngType":0,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Spain","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1},
{"Id":4509293,"Rcvr":13019,"HasSig":false,"Icao":"44CE6D","Bad":false,"Reg":"OO-SSM","FSeen":"\/Date(1512567029549)\/","TSecs":1,"CMsgs":1,"Alt":23700,"GAlt":23700,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"A319","Mdl":"Airbus A319 112","Man":"Airbus","CNum":"1388","Op":"Brussels Airlines","OpIcao":"BEL","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":2,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Belgium","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1,"Year":"2000"},
{"Id":4960709,"Rcvr":11071,"HasSig":true,"Sig":15,"Icao":"4BB1C5","Bad":false,"Reg":"TC-LNE","FSeen":"\/Date(1512567029189)\/","TSecs":1,"CMsgs":4,"Alt":41000,"GAlt":41000,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"A333","Mdl":"Airbus A330 303","Man":"Airbus","CNum":"1706","Op":"Turkish Airlines","OpIcao":"THY","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":3,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Turkey","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1,"Year":"2015"},
{"Id":11260420,"Rcvr":11012,"HasSig":true,"Sig":30,"Icao":"ABD204","Bad":false,"Reg":"N8606C","FSeen":"\/Date(1512567029096)\/","TSecs":2,"CMsgs":1,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"B738","Mdl":" BOEING 737-8H4","Man":"Boeing","CNum":"35964","Op":"Southwest Airlines","OpIcao":"SWA","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":2,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"United States","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1},
"""

parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

print(parsed_json['Type'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json string is invalid.

```
import json
json_string = """[{"Id":3429058,"Rcvr":11182,"HasSig":true,"Sig":6,"Icao":"3452C2","Bad":false,"FSeen":"\/Date(1512567030924)\/","CMsgs":2,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":0,"Species":0,"EngType":0,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Spain","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1},
{"Id":4509293,"Rcvr":13019,"HasSig":false,"Icao":"44CE6D","Bad":false,"Reg":"OO-SSM","FSeen":"\/Date(1512567029549)\/","TSecs":1,"CMsgs":1,"Alt":23700,"GAlt":23700,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"A319","Mdl":"Airbus A319 112","Man":"Airbus","CNum":"1388","Op":"Brussels Airlines","OpIcao":"BEL","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":2,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Belgium","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1,"Year":"2000"},
{"Id":4960709,"Rcvr":11071,"HasSig":true,"Sig":15,"Icao":"4BB1C5","Bad":false,"Reg":"TC-LNE","FSeen":"\/Date(1512567029189)\/","TSecs":1,"CMsgs":4,"Alt":41000,"GAlt":41000,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"A333","Mdl":"Airbus A330 303","Man":"Airbus","CNum":"1706","Op":"Turkish Airlines","OpIcao":"THY","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":3,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Turkey","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1,"Year":"2015"},
{"Id":11260420,"Rcvr":11012,"HasSig":true,"Sig":30,"Icao":"ABD204","Bad":false,"Reg":"N8606C","FSeen":"\/Date(1512567029096)\/","TSecs":2,"CMsgs":1,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"B738","Mdl":" BOEING 737-8H4","Man":"Boeing","CNum":"35964","Op":"Southwest Airlines","OpIcao":"SWA","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":2,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"United States","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1}]
"""
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

for i in parse_json:
    if "Type" in i:
        print (i['Type'])
```

Comment: So when I add in more of the ADS-B feed, which should be all the same data, I come up with a UnicodeDecodeError.

I checked to make sure that the square brackets are in the same place as your example, but no joy.

Comment: Here is my example where I add more data:
https://pastebin.com/ce63GZ0P

I looked over the json.org page on formatting, but I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @OutlawBandit You should not put a comma after the last object. so the end should be `}]` and not `},]`

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is wrong. It contains an array of objects which should be within the square [] brackets.

Change your json string to

```
json_string = """[{"Id":3429058,"Rcvr":11182,"HasSig":true,"Sig":6,"Icao":"3452C2","Bad":false,"FSeen":"\/Date(1512567030924)\/","CMsgs":2,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":0,"Species":0,"EngType":0,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Spain","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1},
{"Id":4509293,"Rcvr":13019,"HasSig":false,"Icao":"44CE6D","Bad":false,"Reg":"OO-SSM","FSeen":"\/Date(1512567029549)\/","TSecs":1,"CMsgs":1,"Alt":23700,"GAlt":23700,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"A319","Mdl":"Airbus A319 112","Man":"Airbus","CNum":"1388","Op":"Brussels Airlines","OpIcao":"BEL","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":2,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Belgium","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1,"Year":"2000"},
{"Id":4960709,"Rcvr":11071,"HasSig":true,"Sig":15,"Icao":"4BB1C5","Bad":false,"Reg":"TC-LNE","FSeen":"\/Date(1512567029189)\/","TSecs":1,"CMsgs":4,"Alt":41000,"GAlt":41000,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"A333","Mdl":"Airbus A330 303","Man":"Airbus","CNum":"1706","Op":"Turkish Airlines","OpIcao":"THY","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":3,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Turkey","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1,"Year":"2015"},
{"Id":11260420,"Rcvr":11012,"HasSig":true,"Sig":30,"Icao":"ABD204","Bad":false,"Reg":"N8606C","FSeen":"\/Date(1512567029096)\/","TSecs":2,"CMsgs":1,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"B738","Mdl":" BOEING 737-8H4","Man":"Boeing","CNum":"35964","Op":"Southwest Airlines","OpIcao":"SWA","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":2,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"United States","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1}]
"""
```